# Can I alter the code and name user fileds of an user table in SAP Business One

Tags: sap-business-one-di-api

When you create a user table, the Code and Name fields are always created by default and I was wondering if I could eliminate the Name field and leave the Code field but as a primary key and of type int for example without this affecting subsequent version updates.

Or altering this would cause problems of some kind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible, if you did it that would terminate support form SAP.